# Aceptar pagos (SOLO CON TARJETA) por mercadopago (PHP)

Tags: php, html, mercadopago, checkout

Bien, tengo integrada en mi pagina la API de mercadopago la cual funciona correctamente, me deja realizar pagos y todo con normalidad... ahora la consulta que yo tengo es esta: cuando le doy al boton de pagar, me da las opciones de pagar con tarjeta de credito o con efectivo, sea en la sucursal que sea, yo necesito que la opcion de pagar en efectivo desaparezca, que solo quede la opcion de pagar con tarjeta de credito... Adjunto codigo del script implementado mas abajo:

```
<script
   src="https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/integrations/v1/web-payment-checkout.js"
   data-preference-id="<?php echo $preference->id; ?>">
</script>
```

Actualizo con mas de mi código que creo es útil para comprender:

````
require __DIR__ .  '/vendor/autoload.php';
// Agrega credenciales
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken('TEST-4253088970004040-070515-668615ecee86224b8cac4df5c80d83c6-780970548');

// Create a preference object
$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();
$preference->back_urls = array(
    "success" => "https://localhost/Carrito-De-Compras-Master/thankyou.php?id_venta=".$_GET['id_venta']."&metodo=mercado_pago",
    "failure" => "https://localhost/Carrito-De-Compras-Master/errorpago.php?error=failure",
    "pending" => "https://localhost/Carrito-De-Compras-Master/errorpago.php?error=pending"
);
$preference->auto_return = "approved";

// Create a preference item
$datos=array();
while ($f = mysqli_fetch_array($datos3)) {
    $item = new MercadoPago\Item();
    $item->title = $f['nombre_producto'];
    $item->quantity = $f['cantidad'];
    $item->unit_price = $f['precio'];
    $datos[]=$item;
}


$preference->items = $datos;
$preference->save();```
````

Comment: Esto depende básicamente de lo que configures en la integración, no? Revisaste la documentación de la API y los ejemplos?

Comment: Era tan fácil y no logre verlo a la primera, tome en cuenta tu comentario, revise la documentación y me encontré con esto: 
`$preference->payment_methods = array(

  "excluded_payment_types" => array(
    array("id" => "ticket")
  )
);`
Con lo cual soluciona el problema que tenia... muchas gracias @Alfabravo

Comment: Súper! Puedes poner tú mismo la respuesta a tu pregunta abajo en la sección de Respuestas para que los demás sepan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Era tan fácil y no logre verlo a la primera, revise la documentación de la API y ejemplos. Me encontré con esto:

```
$preference->payment_methods = array(
"excluded_payment_types" => array(
array("id" => "ticket")   
) );
```

Lo cual crea una nueva preferencia y con `"excluded_payment_types"` excluyo los medios de pago de tipo "ticket" que son los pagos en efectivo.

Deocumentacion completa: [MercadoPago Checkout Pro](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/guides/online-payments/checkout-pro/configurations)